# reduce the time of the backtracking algorithm

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to solve a problem using backtracking. I must use backtracking, given the appearance of an n * n array(arr), and n <= 20.
I should make a given shape with all the buttons not pressed. I may have multiple answers, but I should print the answer with the minimum number of times you press the button.

Pressing the button changes the status of the pressed button and the up, down, left, and right buttons. # is not pressed button, O is pressed button

For example,

4

O O O O

O O O O

O O O O

O O O O

Is given as an input

# O # #

# # # O

O # # #

# # O #

Should be output.

This means that you can make the shape given by the input with four operations (push the button in the O position).

My source code will take about 1 minute in worst case if n is given as 20.

**Is there a way to reduce the time it takes?**

But I do not get a sense of what to do.

The current non-promising condition I am using is that `arr[row-1][col]` and `temarr[row-1][col]` are not the same when manipulating the button at `temans[row][col]`.
This is because I can not change the appearance of temarr [row-1] [col] after this position.

start:
button in 1,1 position:   p       np

button in 1,2 position: p np  p np

...

button in i,j position: p np...p np

button in n,n position: p np...p np

I have solved this by showing the number of all cases of pressed(p) and not pressed(np) the button at a specific position in a tree form.

**I solved this problem**

Comment: Your question does not actually contain a sentence with a question mark. It may be good to more clearly specify what you are asking.

Comment: thank you. I add a sentence

Comment: Usually, backtracking behaves like DFS (did not check your algo), so this would not necessarily find the shortest sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to reduce the time it takes?

Run it on a better computer ? Just joking ^^.

It seems you are a student and it really looks like a homework, so I'm just giving some hints & leads.

- Let's say that at some point in your backtracking, you "know" (=compute) that there are 35 different values between `arr` and `temarr`. You also know that `count - temcount == 3` (you can press only 2 buttons if you want to find a better solution). How likely are you to find a better solution ?
- `compare` function: let's say I place 20*20 = 4,000 playing cards on a table. After counting for 30min, I know that 1,800 are "face up", and 2,200 are "face down". Now I flip 3 cards from "face up" to "face down", and I flip 2 different cards the other way. Do I have to spend 30min counting again to get the 2 totals ?
  Back to your case: each time you modify 5 values in `temarr`, do you have to recompare all its values to `arr`'s values to test if they are different ?
- you are currently computing `temarr` for the sole purpose of comparing it to `arr`, and you are doing the comparison quite often. You can work directly on the "difference" of the two arrays: meaning you have a single array telling which value is "right" or "wrong".

Comment: @mille: If you feel as though this answer has adequately addressed your question and is the best of the answers you've received, you can "Accept" it by clicking the outline of a checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Rechard : Thank you! I check this answer